# Duplicate a product in Voyager Admin Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce, admin, voyager

I'm using voyager admin panel for my website. I have more than 3000 products.
How Can I add duplicate/clone a product button in voyager admin panel?

Comment: why don't you duplicate in your database

Comment: I want to keep an option in admin panel so I click on the button and product will duplicate. But I don't know the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

it may be a method to query the id db you want to duplicate and add its properties back to the database.